# Django Channels with MQTT

Tags: python, django, mqtt, django-channels, paho

Am trying to create websocket using django channels and integrate mqtt with channels and mqtt publish message should be received by the function inside consumer.py should be sent to websocket client.
I have consumer channel like below

consumer.py

```
from channels.consumer import AsyncConsumer
from paho.mqtt import client as Mqtt

class Testing(AsyncConsumer):
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        obj = Mqtt.Client()  
        obj.connect("localhost", 1883, 60)
        obj.on_message = self.updater
        obj.subscribe("Testing")
        obj.loop_start()


    async def updater(self, arg1, arg2, message):
           print(message)
           await self.send({
                "type": "websocket.send",
                "text": message})

    async def websocket_receive(self, text_data):
        pass
```

In the above mqtt connection has happened but if I publish a message to the topic its not working. updater function inside consumer.py is not being called. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

After coming here looking for help on this topic myself I created [chanmqttproxy](https://pypi.org/project/chanmqttproxy/)

Essentially it's a fully async Channels 3 proxy to MQTT that allows publishing and subscribing. The documentation show how to extend the standard Channels tutorial so chat messages are seen on MQTT topics - and can be sent from MQTT topics to all websocket browser clients.

I looked at MQTTAsgi (and credited it for inspiration) but felt that using a pure async solution with full Channels integration was more appropriate.